# Leetcode Two Sum Python Solution not working when I submit on Leetcode, but works on other compiler

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started using leetcode and I don't know if I'm wrong or if there's some bug in leetcode.

This is the code I typed on Leetcode to solve the Two Sum question that didn't work

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        i=0
        j=0
        for k in nums:
            for l in nums:      
                if i!=j:
                    if (nums[i]+nums[j])==target:
                        return [i,j]
                j+=1
            j=0
            i+=1
```

This is the code I typed on Programiz online compiler that worked

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        i=0
        j=0
        for k in nums:
            for l in nums:      
                if i!=j:
                    if (nums[i]+nums[j])==target:
                        return [i,j]
                j+=1
            j=0
            i+=1

testCase=[3,2,4]
target=6
test=Solution()
print(test.twoSum(testCase,target))
```

Both of them had the same test case, but my code works on programiz and not on Leetcode

Comment: What error does leetcode give you? You might just be too slow.

Comment: I got an "Output Limit Exceeded" Status when I submit it. What do you mean I might just be too slow?

Comment: That is a very strange error code indeed, considering your program. Are you sure you don't have a stray `print` statement somewhere?

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that. I removed the print statements that I used for debugging and got the status of "Time Limit Exceeded"

Comment: Yes, that means your solution is too slow. You just need to be smarter about how you compute the final result! That is the difficulty of leetcode, often the 'obvious' solution doesn't work and there exists a smarter, faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you mentioned

> Time Limit Exceeded

Although the code runs fine for some small inputs, it fails the time limit of one big input,
because of two for loops.

Try this,

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
     dic = {}
    
    for i, v in enumerate(nums):
        remaining = target - v
        
        if remaining in dic:
            return [dic[remaining], i]
        dic[v] = i
```